# gotfocus event in vb.net alternative

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i tried the gotfocus event in my form and im having problem.
if i have two form showed, even i put a code

```
Private Sub ChatUI_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
    MsgBox("1")
  End Sub
```

my msgbox doesnt execute when i click the form with that code.
is there any event that determine if my clickedform is the active form then executes a code when my form got clicked or focused or what so on. im using this code in my chat program.
i have chatpanel where i can see who is online/offline users. if i have a message on one of the user, the background color of that control will be red. i want to make the background color of that control to be default when i refocus in the conversation between that user

thanks for the help.

what are other alternatives for this event.

Comment: Adding a MsgBox inside a GotFocus event is the sure way to crash everything. Use the Form.Activate event

Comment: sir steve is it the same with the gotfocus event? the activated event?

Comment: i just use the msgbox as sample code. by the way thanks sir for the alternative event